# Can't find bottleneck in Gaussian Elimination implementation using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

In my numerical methods class last semester I implemented gaussian elimination in c++ with eigen and scored it against the built in methods in eigen.
I now for my fellow students am trying to translate all my codes from c++/eigen to numpy, I also (thought wrongfully) feel more comfortable with numpy and python.

However, this code below is several magnitudes slower to the point where I am sure I made a mistake.
Yet it looks exactly like the c++ code.

I thought it might be the row-major/column-major ordering but that didn't improve anything.

If someone can spot my error and point out what is causing this super slowdown I'd be very grateful.

```
def gauss_elimination(A, b, show_steps = True):
#A = np.asfortranarray(A)
n = A.shape[0]
Ab = np.zeros((n, n+1))
Ab[:,:n] = Ab[:, :n] + A
Ab[:, n] = b
if (show_steps):
    print(Ab)
#turn the matrix into step form
for i in range(n-1):
    pivot = Ab[i,i] #select pivot
    for row in range(i + 1, n):
        factor = Ab[row, i] / pivot #get factor
        if (show_steps):
            print(f"Subtracting {factor} times the {i} row from the {row} row")
        Ab[row, i:] = Ab[row, i:] - Ab[i, i:] * factor #subtract factor times previous row 
        #from current row after pivot column
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if(show_steps):
            print(Ab)
        
#backsubstituion
if (Ab[n-1, n-1] == 0):
    print("0 Pivot")
Ab[n-1, n] = Ab[n-1, n] / Ab[n-1, n-1]
for i in range(n-1)[::-1]: #traverse from the bottom row up
    for k in range(i+1, n): #iterate over found solutions so far
        Ab[i, n] = Ab[i, n] - Ab[k, n] * Ab[i, k] #subtract the solution x[k] times Ab[i, k] from solution column
        if (Ab[i, i] == 0):
            print("Pivot = 0")
        Ab[i, n] = Ab[i, n]/ Ab[i, i] #normalize i.e. get a leading one on the diag
#save solution
x = Ab[:, n]
if (show_steps):
    print(f"Solution \n {x.transpose()}")
return x
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I'm no expert, I don't think so, and the difference shouldn't be that drastic and fast implementations are possible as the built in scipy and numpy implementations show.

Comment: The fast `numpy` methods are writen in `c` (possibly via `cython`), and thus compiled.  Whole array operatikns using those methods are fast, but iterations as you do are slow.  Take a look at  SO questions with words like 'eleminate loops' or 'vectorize' in the title.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you very much, I do remember numpy being a c implementation and thus the discrepency was really puzzling (as c++ is also just C in a way). The difference between the built-ins was also several orders of magnitudes. Thanks to you I've found some answers to read and study carefully thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your python code is about 100x slower than C++ that's ok. You can find benchmarks on the web to give an idea of how fast is python compared to C++[[1]](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/gpp-python3.html)

Note that you have a time.sleep in your code. Removing that your function runs in 15ms for a 32x32.

Your code has `O(n^2)` complexity in python, and `O(n^3)` operations on CPU level. If you are testing with moderate `n` the python interpreter overhead will dominate. As you increase the size of the matrix you start to get less difference between the two run times.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought I messed up complexity, but cubic was intended. Yet my c code I can run in a few seconds up to n = 256 and this python code above n = 32 just stalls and takes forever. n = 16 is already in the minutes.

Comment: wholly maccaroni! I thought you made a joke, but omg! Thank you so much! I can't believe I overlooked this. I had it originally there for printing.